# Getting exception on connecting Jakarta EE project to H2 database

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, h2, h2-console

I'm trying to connect my Jakarta EE 9.1.0 project to H2 database but I get this exception:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Duplicate property
> "USER" [90066-212]

Here is my persistance.xml file (version="3.0") `persistence-unit` part:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:global/dataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And web.xml file (version="5.0") `data-source` and `H2Console servlet` parts:

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:global/dataSource</name>
    <class-name>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</class-name>
    <url>jdbc:h2:file:D:/testdb;USER=sa;PASSWORD=123</url>
</data-source>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/h2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in pom.xml file I add this H2 dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.212</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please help fix the coding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added this two lines in *persistence.xml* file and the error fixed:

```
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
```

---

Complete `persistence-unit` tag of persistence configuration (persistence.xml) is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:global/dataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```